# How to get value from ng-repeat when event not from element within ng-repeat (i.e. not ng-click)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I have a lookahead fuzzy search directive for category tagging:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Apply Tags" ng-keydown="checkKeyDown($event)" ng-change="searchTags()" ng-model="searchText">
<div ng-show="searchText.length>0">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="tag in suggestedTags | fuzzySearch : searchText : 'OR' track by $index" ng-class="{active : $index === selectedIndex}">
            {{tag}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is how I'm handling things

```
suggestedTags: array of strings that is the full list of tags I want to match
selectedIndex: the index of the filtered suggestedTags, based on searchText
searchText: the string I'm using to match up with suggestedTags
```

When I type something, the fuzzy search checks to see if what I typed matches anything into an array, and shortens the list of suggested results. ***This works fine***.

However, I have the following code which allows me to use the keyboard to select from the filtered list (using up, down, and enter keys):

```
scope.checkKeyDown = function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 40) { //down key, increment selectedIndex
    event.preventDefault();
    if(scope.selectedIndex+1 !== scope.suggestedTags.length){ // check to see if at end of list
      scope.selectedIndex++;
    }
  } else if (event.keyCode === 38) { //up key, decrement selectedIndex
    event.preventDefault();
    if(scope.selectedIndex-1 !== -1){ // check to see if at top of list
      scope.selectedIndex--;
    }
  } else if (event.keyCode === 13) { //enter pressed
    event.preventDefault();
    scope.addToSelectedTags(scope.selectedIndex); //adds to selected tags
  }
}
scope.addToSelectedTags = function (index) {
  if(scope.selectedTags.indexOf(scope.suggestedTags[index]) > -1) return; // Test to see if selectedTags already has this value
    scope.selectedTags.push(scope.suggestedTags[index]);
};
```

The problem here is that selectedIndex will be the index from the *filtered* list, but when I push to selectedTags, it's going to be from the full suggestedTags array.

The easiest way to do this is just passing in the string value from whatever is selected. How can I do this? Is there a way to put ng-model on the `<li>` (which repeats), and have it select whatever is active?

Comment: First you need the function that you are calling to actually be in the ng-repeat and then you can use something like - checkKeyDown($event, this) and 'this' is actually the object that you are repeating. I don't know if that is what you meant in the title. Of course you need to reference 'this' in the function as every other parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function Ctrl($scope, $filter) {
  var suggestedTags = ['javascript', 'angular', 'android', 'java', 'c++', 'c#', 'object-c']
  $scope.selectedIndex = 0;
  $scope.filteredTags = suggestedTags;
  $scope.selectedTags = [];
  $scope.checkKeyDown = function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 40) { //down key, increment selectedIndex
      console.log('down');
      event.preventDefault();
      if ($scope.selectedIndex + 1 !== $scope.filteredTags.length) { // check to see if at end of list
        $scope.selectedIndex++;
      }
    } else if (event.keyCode === 38) { //up key, decrement selectedIndex
      console.log('up')
      event.preventDefault();
      if ($scope.selectedIndex - 1 !== -1) { // check to see if at top of list
        $scope.selectedIndex--;
      }
    } else if (event.keyCode === 13) { //enter pressed
      event.preventDefault();

      $scope.addToSelectedTags($scope.selectedIndex); //adds to selected tags
      console.log('enter');
    }
  }

  $scope.searchTags = function() {
    $scope.selectedIndex = 0;
    $scope.filteredTags = $filter('filter')(suggestedTags, $scope.q);
  }

  $scope.addToSelectedTags = function(index) {
    if ($scope.filteredTags.length - 1 >= index) {
      var selectedTag = $scope.filteredTags[index];
      //angular doesnt like duplicate in ng-repeat
      //if you want to have duplicate tag name, you can use track by 
      //or create new object so angular doesnt see it as duplicated

      if ($scope.selectedTags.indexOf(selectedTag) < 0)
        $scope.selectedTags.push(selectedTag);
    }

  }
}
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.11/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <input tpye="text" ng-model="q" ng-keydown="checkKeyDown($event)" ng-change="searchTags()" />
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="tag in filteredTags" ng-class="{active : $index === selectedIndex}">{{tag}}</li>
  </ul>

  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="t in selectedTags">{{t}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You used 'addToSelectedTags()' again, not sure if that was intentional or did you mean to use a different name? If this was intentional, wouldn't this function trigger twice? Once when checkKeyDown() is triggered, and once when a key is pressed when the li item is in focus? I also believe ng-keydown requires element to be in focus so not sure if this will work for li item.

Comment: @PGT your concern about the element focus is right, there are ways to handle to the focus but I reckon to have a extra container to store the filtered result will be better, please check my updated code

Comment: Yep, I didn't get a chance to update my question but I found that you can use $filter in controller and put filtered results in separate variable. Thanks.